# Regex for finding repeating patterns in a phone number? Or perhaps not?

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to find numbers with a pattern, out of a list of several thousand, and I'd like to match things like:

- Sequence of 3 or more, either direction (345,2345,876)
- Repeated sequence (2233,3355,77777) 147,258,369 or their reverse.
- Repeated pattern (373737,33773377)

In a JSON object like this:

```
["ok", {"series/020" : ["02034353637", "02034445673", "02034147369", "02034653185"]}]
```

So all of those would match; for example the first one has 34 35 36, the second has both 444 and 567, the last has both 147 and/or 369, etc.

**What have I tried?** Well, most of the sites in that little box nagging me on the right! Stackoverflow search. Some online books... but I was starting to wonder if there's such a thing as "regex dyslexia" (regexia?), or perhaps it's just thickness, when I found the [142 page book](https://www.princeton.edu/~mlovett/reference/Regular-Expressions.pdf). I know when I'm beat.

With hindsight, it perhaps would have been far quicker and easier to just do an "array of array searches" manually building up the patterns with the help of Google Sheets autofill, but is it even a possible thing?

Finally, is there a "pay me $10 and I'll do your regex for you" site? If not, their should be! They'd make a mint! Thank you.

Comment: Try http://www.regexr.com/, in my humble opinion, the best online regex composer and tester I have seen :)

Comment: Do it as you said: Build up an array of possible matches and check them against your telephone numbers. A regex alone solution would be monstrous. The last phrase is worth thinking of, indeed :-)

Comment: By "either direction"

Comment: @andcl85 I'd have to disagree with you.  I used to believe, too - until I found [regex101.com](http://www.regex101.com) :P  www.rexegg.com is a great resource website that I've found that has helped advance all the way up to `backtracking control verbs`.

Comment: Which regexp site you like best is entirely irrelevant, since this problem is somewhere between theoretically impossible and extremely difficult to solve using regexp. And I'm not sure what you mean by "manually building up patterns". The only solution would seem to be a custom validation program, which shouldn't be horribly hard to write, especially if performance is not a huge concern.

Comment: would a javascript function be ok for you as well? I could do that

Comment: You'll need to define your problem more thoroughly to accomplish this with a regex. Here are the possible sequences I recognize: 1. Incrementing by 1 2. Incrementing by 2 3. incrementing by 3 4. Incrementing by 4 5. Decrementing by 1 6. Decrementing by 2 7. Decrementing by 3 8. Decrementing by 4 9. 4 or more alternating characters 10. 2 or more alternating pairs 11. 3 or more repeated characters 12. Matching separator characters with incrementing intervening characters 13. Matching separator characters with decrementing intervening characters Anything else? Would you like fries with that?

Comment: @Erutan409 Very nice regex site, regex101.com! I did not know about it. I will take a look. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can write is as one RegEx, but for readability I left it like that:

```js
var data = ["ok", {
  "series/020": [
    "02034353637", "02034445673", "02034147369", "02034653185",
    "345", "2345", "876",
    "2233", "3355", "77777",
    "147", "258", "369",
    "373737", "33773377",
  ]
}]

var numbers = data[1]["series/020"]

var patternNumbers = numbers.filter(isPatternNumber)

// Demo output
document.write("<pre>" + JSON.stringify(patternNumbers, null, "\t") + "</pre>")
document.write("Matched " + patternNumbers.length + " out of " + numbers.length)

function isPatternNumber(n) {
  // constant pattern
  if (/147|258|369/.test(n)) return true

  // repeating pattern 3+
  if (/(?=(\d))\1{3,}/.test(n)) return true

  // sequence asc 3+
  if (/012|123|234|345|456|567|678|789/.test(n)) return true
    // sequence desc 3+
  if (/987|876|765|654|543|432|321/.test(n)) return true

  // repeating double sequence xxyy (note that x=y is possible, same as 4 in a row)
  if (/(?=(\d))\1{2}(?=(\d))\2{2}/.test(n)) return true

  // alternerting pattern xyxy (note that x=y is possible, => same as 4 in a row)
  if (/(?=(\d))\1{1}(?=(\d))\2{1}(?=(\d))\1{1}(?=(\d))\2{1}/.test(n)) return true

  return false
}

// Demo Input
var input = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0]
var output = document.getElementsByTagName("span")[0]
input.oninput = function() {
  output.textContent = isPatternNumber(input.value)
}
```

```html
Test a number:
<input type="text" /> <span></span>
```

Comment: Wow - what can I say? Above and beyond the call of duty. An example that does everything right out of the box AND comes with a code snippet (I never knew they existed!). Thank you so much. And I can even work out what you've done, although I'd never have got there, ever. Perfect! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

repeating digits and repeating pattern are pretty simple in this case

```
(\d+?)\1+
```

assuming that this is the first/only bracket in the total regex

the sequences take a little more effort, especially if we are talking about sequences of dynamic length.
i wrote a litte JS-function to build such a regex

```
function sequencedDigitsRegex(minLength, maxLength){
    //the last digit
    var t = "'+a[0]+'?";
    //the optional Part
    for(var i=1; i<maxLength - minLength; ++i)
        t = "(?:'+a["+(i%10)+"]+'" + t + ")?";

    //the required part
    for(t = "'" + t + "'"; minLength>0; --minLength)
        t = "a["+(i++%10)+"] + " + t;

    //a template-method
    var template = new Function("a", "return " + t);
    var digits = "98765432109876543210".split("");

    //the regex-parts
    var out = new Array(20);
    for(var i=0; i<10; ++i){
        var a = digits.slice(i, i+10);
        out[i] = template(a);
        //also include the reversed variant
        out[i+10] = template(a.reverse());
    }
    //join the parts into one, long regex
    return new RegExp("("+out.join("|")+")", "g")
}
```

if you want to combine them you could do sth. like this:

```
var repeatingPattern = /(\d+?)\1+/g;   
var sequencePattern = sequencedDigitsRegex(2,8);
var patterns = new RegExp(repeatingPattern.source + "|" + sequencePattern.source, "g");
```

Comment: `/(\d+?)\1+/` also matches double digits

Comment: that was the intention.

Comment: maybe ask if it is considered a pattern, i don't think so. However with that regex `(\d+?)\1{2,}` is pretty genious for these patterns :D it also matches xyxyxy

Comment: Thank you, @Thomas. I'm going to have to look at this more closely tomorrow as I can't seem to match the solution to my problem. But, thank you. It's interesting to learn from.